# Оптимизация трех циклов

Tags: delphi, циклы

Можно ли как-то ускорить выполнение трех циклов? Два из них вложенных. Надо пробегать по массиву и собирать все возможные комбинации, складывая три этих члена массива. Если в массиве там *100000* элементов, то это растягивается на довольно долго время.

```
    for i:=0 to n-1 do
      for j:=0 to n-1 do
        for k:=0 to n-1 do
         begin
          s:=s+Arr[i] + Arr[j] + Arr[k];
         end;
```

Comment: Под "сложением" - вы имеете в виду "конкатенацию"?

Comment: @ViktorTomilov, добавил

Comment: @EgorRandomize, нет, там целые числа внутри массива

Comment: @Erm, хорошо. А чем у Вас наполнен `Arr[]`?

Comment: @EgorRandomize, целые числа.

Answer (score 6, accepted):

Я не думаю, что стоит применять в этом случае что-либо вроде TParallel.For или придумывать что-то серьезнее. Код не оптимален при больших n просто потому, что не нужно три цикла, стоит просто внимательнее посмотреть и посчитать чисто математически:

```
s:=0;
for i:=0 to n-1 do inc(s,ar[i]);
s:=3*sqr(n)*s;
```

И вот уже к этому коду, если n будет просто огромным, можно присобачивать TParallel.For, если подумать :)

**Update 1**

Нет, овчинка выделки не стоит. На таких простых вычислениях TParallel.For проигрывает: взглянул итоговый ассемблерный код - там получается 4 вызова функции, которые губят весь выигрыш :)